# How to read all (current) user session in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have search a lot to read all the current user session in jsp, java and spring mvc but not able to find.I have found one for ASP.NET at [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/05/reading-all-users-session.aspx). Can any help me how to do this in java/jsp/spring mvc. I am looking for reading session of all users which are currently logged.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Are you looking for reading session of *all users currently logged*

Comment: @ejb_guy, Yes I am looking this. I need code or API link. Why -1?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of API which can allow you this. Even from security POV this should not be allowed ( One user looking at what is data in other user session). Having said that there are ways to do this. You can put the reference of each session in AppContext (for ex HashMap in AppContext storing userid and session) and from there you can access all session.
PS: Nope i havenot downvoted your question.

Comment: Thanks. But there are various issues with this approach. for example, timout management. Since I am reading this in server, there is no security issue with this approach.

Comment: hmmm...yeap timeout etc will need to be managed and should be fairly starightfowrd as java provides hook for cleanup if session invalidates. Other issue will be synchronization which need to be taken care of. Do let know if you found any API for this. Though reading session of other user is surely a security issue. Even you are using it on server, you are providing a way where one user can have access to all other user session data,